# IntelliJ compiles successfully but no signed apk is generated

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I recently updated my android SDK platform, since the update when i try to generate a signed APK in intelliJ idea i get no error in compilation and packaging process (even proguard works fine) but no apk file is generated in the destination. I am able to run my app on emulator and devices, means that debug apk is generated correctly.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding, no luck. I thought that this might be a problem with project settings, so i tried to generate APKs for other android projects or even an empty Hello World project, the problem still exists.

Is there any log files or other things that i can post here to help clarify the problem?

[image: SDK manager screenshot]

Comment: Please describe in steps how do you "generate APK" currently? We'd like to understand what steps did you take before we troubleshoot.

Comment: @ezaquarii Well, selecting `Generate Signed APK` from `build` menu as i always did. Before updating SDK i had no problem with generating and publishing APKs. I double checked my keystore, key alias and their passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was an irrelevant (to android SDK) problem that i was struggling with last two days.

The problem solved by removing following directory:

```
%HOME%\.IntelliJIdea14\system\caches
```

Comment: This unfortunately didnt help me. I deleted that directory but still having the same issue. Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

had just the very same trouble, have tried around and got it to my surprise. So the how do to is a better hint:

Make an Ant-Build
Build .. Generate ant  on the left side add it press "play"
Build your project.release .. 
   ..  .. Now here I got a clear Error message:
"wrong android sdk build-tools version"  hopefully you will get the right for you.
some apk's were generated but not installed on a phone.
Still I was not able to generate signed apk.
Deleted the ant build xx .., restarted IntelliJ  15.x
tried.xx.. now it works. hope it helps.